# Can't see the results when querying the table in terminal

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

Can't see the results when querying the table in terminal. Although the database gets created and code runs without an error and I get `table created` message in my console but when I go to terminal and query the databse using tables I get nothing. No table has been created

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def createdb():

    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("sports")


    if not db.open():
        print(db.isOpen())
        print("not open")

        return False

    query=QSqlQuery()

    query.exec_("create table login( username varchar(10), password varchar(10))")
    print ("table created")

    return True


if __name__=='__main__':

    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    createdb()
```

result:

> sqlite> .databases
>   seq  name             file
>
> ---

0    main             /Users/sachinsharma/sports.db

Comment: Don't you have to commit the "create" query?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work with that either. I still get nothing

Comment: sqlite> select * from login;
Error: no such table: login
sqlite>

Comment: `"sports" != "sports.db"`.

Comment: I actually found the solution. The .db file that is being created by my ide which is pycharm is in the application folder while when I use terminal it searches for the same file in my home directory and not the directory in which the program is creating the actual file and hence whenever I used to type in .open followed by name of my db a new empty db used to get created in home directory.